# controlling ceiling fan speed to minimal

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, fan

Currently, the fan is still fast for me on number 1 speed. Is it possible and how to reduce this speed further using any device.

Comment: Yeah, use a resistor. If you want a decent answer, write a decent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible to reduce the speed by a limited amount. Ceiling fan speed reduction is done by various means of making the fan weaker so that the load will slow it down. The voltage could be reduced by inserting inductance or resistance in series or using electronic voltage reduction. However, the motor is probably designed to work over a specific speed range with a specific fan design. In trying to reduce the speed more than it is reduced with the original design, the motor may just stall. Theoretically, the frequency could be reduced by reducing the frequency, but that too has limitations when used for a single phase motor and would likely not be worth the expense.